# The property, 'to', in the request body is invalid (line: -, column: -)

Tags: python, line, bots

I'm new in line bot, I try the line api with trial dev, and this simple python code (from https://developers.line.me/en/docs/messaging-api/reference/#send-push-message) :

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}',
}

data = '{"to": "kutemukan","messages":[{"type":"text","text":"Hello, world1"},{"type":"text","text":"Hello, world2"}]}'

a = requests.post('https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push', headers=headers, data=data)
print(a.text)
```

My line id : `kutemukan` , and from that, I got:

> The property, 'to', in the request body is invalid (line: -, column: -)

thanks, and btw + explain what different Line Bot with Telegram Bot

Answer (score 2):

For your push message case,

1. The simplest way I used is put the bot ID on "userId". Those people add your bot as friend should see message every time when your bot pushed.

You can find id at last section "Other/Your user ID" in [line developer console](https://developers.line.me/en/).

[image]

2. Track the id from response message by webhook tool, like [RequestBin](https://requestb.in), are  free and easy to use. Following steps are modified from [Line bot faq](https://github.com/line/line-bot-faq).

   - Create webhook, open https://requestb.in, create a requestbin
   - Set webhook on Line, open [line developer console], fill the url from RequestBin to webhook URL section
   - Verify, click [Verify] on [line developer console], then verify data on RequestBin inspect after refresh.
   - Find ID, send line message from user or group, then you can find user id or group id in RequestBin "RAW BODY" section.
   - Send message, put the id on your push message, Done

[image: Webhook section]

Answer (score 0):

you need a "real user id" of your account,

i got that from webhook, `{"events":[{"type":"message","replyToken":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,"source":{"userId":"THIS_NEEDED_USER_ID","type":"user"},"timestamp":1509437238106,"message":{"type":"text","id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","text":"Aya"}}]}`